# How to disable Typescript transpiling?

Tags: typescript, babeljs, transpiler

I'd like to disable Typescript's transpiling, keeping all the code as it is, because I'm using Babel on my project. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: The way to disable TypeScript's transpiling is to not use TypeScript.

Comment: I'd like to keep the Typescript's compiling, but I don't want to get my code refactored to a lower version of ECMASCRIPT. I'll use Babel to that.

Comment: So... your question doesn't make a lot of sense then. TypeScript compiles to the version of ECMAScript you tell it to.

Comment: @mike-mccaughan, Typescript is a static type checker! To refactor the code to a target version of ECMASCRIPT is an additional feature, and I'd like to disable it.